# How to work with possible undefined values?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to work with an optional parameter, if said parameter is not included when calling the function, it is assigned a value automatically.

When using this parameter in the global scope of the function I do not receive any error from the linter, the problem appears when I try to use it inside a forEach (I have only tried there).

The following code is an example of what happens:

```
interface opts {
  optionalParam?: number
}

const func = (options: opts): void => {
  // I assign a value to the optional parameter
  options.optionalParam ??= 100

  const obj = {
    test: 8
  }
  obj.test = options.optionalParam * obj.test // ✅ It works perfect

  const objs = [{
    test: 6
  }]
  objs.forEach((obj) => {
    obj.test = options.optionalParam * obj.test // ❌ The object is possibly "undefined".ts(2532)
               ˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆˆ
  })
}
```

I don't fully understand why in one place it detects it as undefined and in another it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is not able to tell the difference between

```
objs.forEach(callback) // code that works with options
```

and

```
doSomethingAsynchronous().then(callback) // code that works with options
```

In the second case, it should be pretty clear why there could be a problem - you might assign an undefined value back to `optionalParam` before the async code runs. (`options.optionalParam = undefined;`) - the property is typed as `number | undefined`.

The first case with `forEach` has a similar problem because you're working with a callback.

One way to do this would be to remove the callback and use a `for` loop instead.

```
for (const obj of objs) {
  obj.test = options.optionalParam * obj.test
}
```

Another approach would be to extract `optionalParam` to a definitely-defined variable.

```
const func = (options: opts): void => {
  const optionalParam = options.optionalParam ?? 100;
  // proceed to reference optionalParam in the future
  // don't reference `options` again
```

or, more concisely

```
const func = ({ optionalParam = 100 }: opts): void => {
```

Comment: Looking at it now calmly it makes sense, in the end I think I'll use:
`const optionalParam = options.optionalParam ?? 100;`
Thanks for the reply!